# Xcode: Combine string with numbers

Tags: xcode, string

+I want to load a certain image by name.
This name is composed of the size and some strings.

The final results should for example be

"button_bg_124_84_down.png" 
(without quotes)

I have

```
CGFloat nWidth = 124;
CGFloat nHeight = 84;
```

How would can I form such a string without any much mocking around, please?

I was hoping that I could simply say

```
NSString * mystring = "button_bg_" + nWidth + "_" + nHeight + "_down.png";
```

but that is seemingly not the way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the docs for `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString * mystring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_bg_%.0f_%.0f_down.png", nWidth, nHeight];
```

EDIT: as you want 222 not 222.000000 so .0f is required to convert it into int value. otherwise decimal will get appended

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that's not the way to concatenate strings. Try this:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_bg_%.0f_%.0f_down.png", nWidth, nHeight];
```

Comment: the result will be button_bg_124.000000_84.000000_down.png

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that using this code:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_bg_%f_%f_down.png", nWidth, nHeight];
```

Comment: the result will be button_bg_124.000000_84.000000_down.png